# Datepicker in button form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I m trying to get a datepicker in calendar icon form.

how to do?

```js
$('#picker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  maxDate: '0'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-YdYyWQf8AS4WSB0WWdc3FbQ3Ypdm0QCWD2k4hgfqbQbRCJBEgX0iAegkl2S1Evma5ImaVXLBeUkIlP6hQ1eYKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-RCgrAvvoLpP7KVgTkTctrUdv7C6t7Un3p1iaoPr1++3pybCyCsCZZN7QEHMZTcJTmcJ7jzexTO+eFpHk4OCFAg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn-change" id="picker">
   <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you now specify more what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you hope to always maintain the calendar icon for your [date picker](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/), even when a date has been selected.

### Option 1

Unfortunately, the [format option](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md#format) doesn't seem to support HTML being sent as the value. The best way I think you could do this in one element would probably be by resetting the HTML of the button when the dialog has closed.

```js
const $picker = $('#picker')

$picker.datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  maxDate: '0',
  hide: () => {
    $picker.html('<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-YdYyWQf8AS4WSB0WWdc3FbQ3Ypdm0QCWD2k4hgfqbQbRCJBEgX0iAegkl2S1Evma5ImaVXLBeUkIlP6hQ1eYKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-RCgrAvvoLpP7KVgTkTctrUdv7C6t7Un3p1iaoPr1++3pybCyCsCZZN7QEHMZTcJTmcJ7jzexTO+eFpHk4OCFAg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn-change" id="picker">
   <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
</button>
```

### Option 2

The next best option would probably be to use two separate objects, a picker and a trigger. The trigger contains our calendar icon and opens the picker when clicked. The picker is hidden behind the trigger and is what the dialog opens to.

```js
const $trigger = $('#date-picker .trigger')

const $picker = $('#date-picker .picker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  maxDate: '0',
  trigger: $trigger
})
```

```css
#date-picker {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#date-picker .picker {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-YdYyWQf8AS4WSB0WWdc3FbQ3Ypdm0QCWD2k4hgfqbQbRCJBEgX0iAegkl2S1Evma5ImaVXLBeUkIlP6hQ1eYKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-RCgrAvvoLpP7KVgTkTctrUdv7C6t7Un3p1iaoPr1++3pybCyCsCZZN7QEHMZTcJTmcJ7jzexTO+eFpHk4OCFAg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="button-container" id="date-picker">
  <button class="btn-change trigger">
    <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="picker"></button>
</div>
```

### Note

Neither of these routes is really good practice. I would highly recommend using a date picker that sits inside of an `<input>` tag and to always display the date. This helps greatly with accessibility and readability.